# Yii File Upload giving empty array in controller

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

Hi please check my following code:

**Model:**

```
 public $image;
/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'file';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('image_url', 'required'),
        array('image_url', 'length', 'max'=>256),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('image_url', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
         array('image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png'),
    );
}
```

**Controler:**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new File;
            print_r($_POST['File']);
             $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php
 $form = $this->beginWidget(
'CActiveForm',
array(
    'id' => 'upload-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)
);

   echo $form->labelEx($model, 'image');
   echo $form->fileField($model, 'image');
   echo $form->error($model, 'image');
   echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); 
   $this->endWidget();?>
```

you can see **print_r($_POST['File']);** in my controller. It gives me empty array with no url or anything regarding the uploaded image. Please help

Thanks

**Solution**

following changes were made in the controller function which worked for me.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new File;
            $model->image_url = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');


            if($model->save())
            $model->image_url->saveAs('D:/xampp/htdocs/project/images/upload/logo.jpg');


    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$model = new Photo;
$model->attributes = $_POST['Photo'];
$model->image = CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');
```